# How can Linux Kernel deal with meaningless wake_up_pocess()?

Tags: linux, sched

For an original open-source Linux kernel, a task(`taskA`) may enter a blocking state(`TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`/`TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE`) when `running futex_wait()` / `running sleep()` / `disk IO wait` / `experiences a page fault interrupt` and so on.
If at this time, another task run `wake_up_process(taskA)`, without sending any signal, is this behavior safe(that is the task will not come back to user mode before futex_wake / sleep end / IO complete / page loaded)?

I have read the code for `futex_wait()`, yes it can handle this situation correctly:

```c
    /*
     * We expect signal_pending(current), but we might be the
     * victim of a spurious wakeup as well.
     */
    if (!signal_pending(current))
        goto retry;
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.9/source/kernel/futex/waitwake.c#L668

However, I can't make sure that everywhere can handle this situation correctly, I can't read all the blocked code in kernel. Are there any constraints to ensure this security?

For example, a task run `sleep(5);`, then handle a signal. When it processing the signal, it blocked again, maybe TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE or TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE. At this time, the sleep time is up and will `wake_up_process(task)` whitout sending any signal (I guess), is this safe?